# Check Printer Status in PHP7

Tags: php, printing, php-7, zebra-printers

I'm testing below code to print labels with custom text

```
    $outputString='^XA
^FO100, 200
^AD,50,25
^FH_^FD Hello world _7E ^FS
^XZ';
     $Ip='xxx.xxx.x.xx';
     $port='xxxx'
        $fp = fsockopen($Ip, $port, $errno, $errstr);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {
        try {
            $kk=fwrite($fp, $outputString, strlen($outputString));
            fclose($fp);
            echo 'Successfully Printed';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
```

It is working fine but I am looking for way to find out any method or way to find out if the printer has printed the data successfully i.e if there is no paper it still prints ***Successfully Printed***

Comment: I doubt it's fully possible without coding something from the printer - it will return successful as you're only checking to see if it gets to the queue - not if it prints (similar issues with using the `mail()` function)

Comment: @treyBake `fwrite` always return the same thing even if the printer prints or not . So do you have any other way to find out ??

Comment: if it is about the queue then maybe analyze the queue data. :(

Comment: No, all PHP will do is check if it got added to the queue successfully and that's where the PHP connection ends

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the ZPL command `~HS` (Host Status).  It returns a three line response with lots of useful information about the current state of the printer.  The first two lines provide flags for label present, paper out, head up, over/under temperature, etc.

See https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf for more details

Comment: I've add ~HS to my zpl code it still returns nothing please guide me!!

Comment: `~HS` is a standalone ZPL command (does not need to be contained in `^XA` ... `^XZ`).  I find it best to send before printing a label.  After sending the `~HS`, your code needs to read from the socket/port until it sees the three `\r\n` terminated lines.  Then parse the mostly fixed-format set of flags and if no error conditions, it is safe to send the label format.